# Looking for jQuery mobile image slideshow compatible with PhoneGap

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, slideshow

I'm looking for a jQuery Mobile image slideshow that is compatible with PhoneGap.

I checked out this one: http://www.photoswipe.com, but there doesn't seem to be an active community around it, e.g. the issues I registered never got answered.
I also had a look at this one: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/05/27/awesome-mobile-image-gallery-web-app/ 
But that makes use of an external XML file, and I don't want to write an XML file for each slideshow that I want to show.

Now, is there a proven image slideshow for jQuery Mobile that is compatible with PhoneGap?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can go for http://www.photoswipe.com/ which is best one.
People have successfully used it with jQuery Mobile.

also you can Try http://swipejs.com/

Comment: hello, is there a way to use photoswipe in a small window instead of using the entire screen of the mobile device? I am looking for something more like the slider of the iPhone App Store snap shots of the apps

Comment: swipeJS allows you to set the size of the slide show.  Plus, it is considerably more lightweight, the un-minified version is only 280 lines of js.  I found it to be more flexible for my app where the content of the slideshow is dynamically updated based on user interaction. +1 for the swipejs.com recommendation!

Comment: @Marci-man if you download it, there is an example showing how to display the images in a fixed sized height window...

Comment: Swipejs is the best :)